# API server on Heroku & NameCheap

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, heroku, namecheap

I have a simple app, api server.
I installed the app on Heroku and everything works fine.
But the same app will not work on NameCheap hosting.

For example, when I send a GET request to "..com/api/posts', it returns nothing, and the request runs indefinitely. And this endpoint should return array from mongodb.
I thought it was up to app, but i assumed it might be up to mongodb connection, so I reworked '..com/api/posts' and set it to return a simple message/posts array, without connecting to mongodb.

```
res.status(200).json({
        posts: [{
            title: 'First Test',
            content: 'This is the first Test'
        }]
    });
```

In which case it works, and returns the answer/array with one post.

So i'm sure its up to connecting to the mongodb database.

But I do not understand why the same code works on localhost, and on Heroku, and it won't on the NameCheap hosting (paid hosting).

Comment: Who hosts your MongoDB database? How do you connect to it?

Comment: How do you mean, who hosts?

Connection to database

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://ckomi:'+ process.env.MONGO_ATLAS_PW +'@cluster0-efywk.mongodb.net/mean-new-second',
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useCreateIndex: true}
)
.then((res) => {
    console.log('Connected to database ')
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log('Connection failed ', err)
})

Comment: OK, so you have a hosted MongoDB instance at https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas? I'd bet it has a whitelist of IP addresses permitted to connect to it.

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer immediately, I couldn't for two days.
At first I thought that the problem was IP, but it's not, I remembered setting the IP (0.0.0.0/0) back in the beginning of the project.
Like I said, the same code is on Heroku and it works.